# Cannot read property 'setValue' of null - Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Need to setValue in fileInfo.

My code:
this.welderCreationForm.controls['wpsQualified'].value[index]['fileInfo'].setValue(data._id);

FormControl:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write it as following:

```
(<FormGroup>(<FormArray>this.welderCreationForm.controls['wpsQualified']).at(index)).controls['fileInfo'].setValue(data._id);
```

Comment: please mark answer useful if it is working for you. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

`fileInfo` is a `formControl` type but you are using it as a usual object property meaning it doesnot have the `setValue` method. Here is some help:

```
 const formArray = this.welderCreationForm.get('wpsQualified') as FormArray;
 formArray.at(index).setValue({fileInfo: data._id });
```

Comment: Thanks.
But getting error "ERROR Error: Must supply a value for form control with name: 'wpsQualified'."

Comment: Yes I expected that because the setValue method enforces all other form control  values to be changed to ignore this change setValue to patchValue to only update a single formControl